# How can i change/edit SOAP response in ASMX

Tags: asp.net, oracle, web-services, soap, wsdl

Im creating a soap web service for our client and I need to change the response from:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <send_messageResponse xmlns="send_message_response">
         <message_response>
            <message_id>2001</message_id>
            <description>sent</description>
            <status>sent</status>
         </message_response>
      </send_messageResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

to

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <send_message_response xmlns="send_message_response">
         <message_response>
            <message_id>2001</message_id>
            <description>sent</description>
            <status>sent</status>
         </message_response>
      </send_messageResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i've tried adding

```
[WebMethod]
        [return: XmlElement("message_response")]
        [SoapDocumentMethod("send_message", RequestNamespace = "urn", ResponseNamespace = "send_message_response", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
```

but still cant change the response. im also wondering if any have experience in creating the Outbound API of Oracle Field Service Cloud? Coz our client is oracle :)

Comment: whats the diff between both?

Comment: <send_messageResponse xmlns="send_message_response"> before
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<send_message_response xmlns="send_message_response"> after